# using libcurl to create a standalone site-polling program

Tags: c, libcurl

I am creating a **standalone (no DLLs) windows C/C++** program that uses HTTP POST to periodically send data to an HTTP server. I identified **libCURL** as the HTTP client library as it seems simple and reliable.

I still need to identify the **environment (an IDE)** which I can use to develop my project. My program has:

1. poller- which checks the status of the connection
2. a file writer when polled link is down
3. a component which POSTs the file when link is up

What is the **appropriate IDE** for this project? I heard endorsements for DevC++ and Visual C.

I am a newb to coding and this site. Pardon me if I am unclear in anything.

Answer (score 0):

Any IDE will fit your need. Just install one of them and start coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). It is light, more easy to work with and has more features than Dev C++.

Comment: And can it statically compile libcurl easily, so that my .exe will be standalone?

Comment: I think you can add compiler options to do that. You may even set the build command.